# Tooltip visibility in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a Class which displays a label. When I hover the mouse over that label there is a empty tooltip being displayed. I would want to remove that tooltip(I mean I dont want it to be shown). I can easily say tooltip.setVisibility(false) but I should not change the code inside the MouseTrackListener Anonymous class. I need to use a toltip property pr anythin else so that when I extend this class I need to have an option to easily set the visibility of this tooltip if needed or disable it if not needed.

Here is my Code snippet (JAVA SWT)

```
tooltip = new ToolTip(parent.getShell(), SWT.NONE);

MouseTrackListener mouseTrackListener = new MouseTrackListener() {
@Override
public void mouseEnter(MouseEvent e) {
    if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {                       
      tooltip.setLocation(Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation().x, 
       Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation().y + TOOLTIP_OFFSET_Y);
       tooltip.setVisible(true);
   }
}

@Override
public void mouseExit(MouseEvent e) {
     if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
          tooltip.setVisible(false);
     }
}

@Override
public void mouseHover(MouseEvent e) {
}};

label.addMouseTrackListener(mouseTrackListener);
iconLabel.addMouseTrackListener(mouseTrackListener);
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not just using `Control.setToolTipText(string)`?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure of what you want to do. Just hide empty tooltips or get control over when a tip is shown?
Maybe this fits your needs:

```
private boolean showToolTip = true;
tooltip = new ToolTip(parent.getShell(), SWT.NONE);

public void setShowToolTip (boolean show){
   showToolTip = show;
}

MouseTrackListener mouseTrackListener = new MouseTrackListener() {
    @Override
public void mouseEnter(MouseEvent e) {
    if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
      tooltip.setLocation(Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation().x, 
      Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation().y + TOOLTIP_OFFSET_Y);
      if (showToolTip){
         tooltip.setVisible(true);
      } else {
         tooltip.setVisible(false);
   }
}
```

Or do you want a solution in which the code in your instance of MouseTrackListerner is not changed?

Answer (score 0):

You could try **ToolTip's** `setAutoHide(boolean autoHide)` property. (not used it, so not sure)

```
if(text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
    tooltip.setAutoHide(true);
}
```

Does this help?